# Updater для программы/игры

Tags: php, java, windows

Учавствую в разработке некой игры и наконец-то устали заливать новую копию игры каждый раз, учитывая что она уже весит 3+ гигов. Решили заранее сделать по крутому и сделать либо сразу лаунчер для игры, но потом быстро отступили от этой идеи и решили сделать хотя бы чисто апдейтер.

**Задача:**

Суть апдейтера должна быть в том что где-то на сервере/хостинге(в т.ч. виртуальном) лежат все эти 3+ гигов игры, когда выходит новая версия - ее заливают туда по FTP с заменой файлов. Когда выходит новая версия игроки могут попросту запустить апдейтер и тот проверит все файлы игры с теми что на хостинге и заменит старые на новые(но при этом не будет закачивать одинаковые).

**Как я предполагаю это должно работать?**

Я не знаю точно ничего про это. Полагаю нужно сделать побайтовую проверку каждого файла что бы точно знать что он старый или новый, но тогда это будет долго и будет большая нагрузка на сервер(наверное, а ведь игру будут закачивать сотни человек, и более того закачивать будут чуть ли не в день релиза обновления сразу все).

Другой вариант сравнивать размеры SHA1 или что-то вроде этого. Но что если в файле будет изменен только 1 символ, есть же какой-то шанс что этот способ пропустит какое-то изменение?

**Инструменты для этого:**

Я не работал с файлами еще так подробно как нужно тут. В основном я работал с веб-технологиями: PHP, JS и все что с ними связано или лежит рядом. Я почитал, их можно использовать с например WinJS, PHP-GTK или мне очень понравился PHP Desktop с его возможностями. Но это звучит как какой-то способ через заднее место. Я слабо знаком с C++ и думаю попробовать реализовать что-то такое на C#.

Но я почти уверен что ничего не нужно придумывать, где возможно уже есть готовое решение, что бы можно было создать обычный update.exe который пройдет по всем файлам и заменит нужные. Я нашел некий electron-builder который возможно сделает что-то подобное, но сперва я хотел бы услышать мнение более опытных людей на эту тему.

Comment: Winjs поддерживает только вин8+ и для доступа к файлам пользователь должен подтвердить выбор нужной папки. Node.js это нормальный вариант для написания консольного приложения, Electron и NW.js, которые для GUI, не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

1. Чтобы обновлять файлы игры, игра должна быть остановлена, чтобы не было проблем с доступом к файла.
2. Игра весит довольно много, еще нужно знать максимальный размер файлов, это так же будет влиять на операцию сравнения файлов.

Приведенные выше два пукнта скорее всего не позволят вам использовать какое-то готовое решение (например lftp), особенно первый. Вам нужно писать свой загрузчик игры, который и будет проверять наличие обновлений и выполнять это обновление, предварительно остановив игру.

Что касается сравнения файлов, то я бы завел регистр версий (хешей) файлов - текстовый докумень. По нему можно было бы и судить, что нужно обновить, а что уже есть. Т.е. один текстовый файл лежит у пользователя, другой на сервере, у обоих версии файлов уже посчитаны, каждый раз вычислять ничего не нужно. При замене файла правим локальный текстовый файл, вставляя актуальные версии хешей.

Единственный минус при таком подходе в том, что если пользователь вручную удалит часть файлов, то ваш обновляетор этого не заметит, так как он опирается на текстовый файл. С другой стороны, можно дописать еще одну утилиту полной проверки файлов, которая будет считать хеш суммы файлов и проверять их с данными из локального тектового файлика.

Структура примерно такая:

```
/data/
    /sounds/
        /sound1.mp3 {sdfu9r72fv83r7wehfsed}
        /sound2.mp3 {df82j0380dusoisdfsdfs}
```

На чем игра, на том, наверное, лучше и писать утилиту для обновления.

Не думаю, что стоит задумываться по поводу коллизий хешей файлов (разные файлы имеют один хеш), это моловероятно.

Comment: Да, на счет хешей я уже нашел пока делал более детальные поиски. Вопрос еще в том как делать хеш? Это только кодировать байтовый размер файла или это что-то другое? 

Файлы будут не очень большие, но их будет довольно много, что приведет к размерам в 3гб. Единственная проблема тут искать надежный хостинг что бы раздавал это за недорого. На счет ручного удаления файлов пользователем ничего не поделаешь, в плане это в интересах игрока не удалить ничего :) Но я понимаю о чем вы, это в планах на будущие версии если будет полезно.

Comment: @Telion Хэши создавать нужно с помощью готовых функций. Они рассчитываются по всем сайтам файла.

Comment: Можно сравнивать файлы по дате изменения.

Comment: Есть готовые библиотеки для сравнения папок по FTP по размеру или дате https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories

Comment: @Telion, хеш делается на основе всего контента файла, только так. Все остальное может не давать нужного результата. Ни даты, ни размеры.

Comment: @DimaG. Что вы скажете на счет http://www.advancedinstaller.com? Создается проект и патчи. Каждый патч включает тот самый кешфайл. Я все еще не разобрался как она работает, но если есть такая программа, наверняка есть и что-то попроще как раз вот для сего проекта. А если я не найду ничего придется учить С# что меня немного напрягает...

Comment: @Telion, мне как программисту на Java трудно судить, мне проще написать за день, чем разбираться несколько часов/дней с вероятностью зайти в тупик или упереться в не 100% подходящий функционал. Сделать подобное решение с нулевым знанием какого-либо из системных языков будет трудновато, хотя на самом деле даже на PHP можно это написать, используя какие-нибудь дополнительные утилиты позволяющие стартовать и останавливать процесс. Предложенная программа платная - это минус на мой взгляд, к тому же ценник весьма бодрый для такой простетской функции.